# What is the difference between Fluent Mapping and Auto mapping in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

After reading some of the articles about Fluent NHibernate I got confused from where to start

I have an existing database to which I need to create DataAccessLayer. I am new to NHibernate and FluentNhibernate. Since I understood that there is no need to write hbm.xml files, I picked Fluent Nhibernate.

So, What is FluentMapping? and AutoMapping?

I have created a classLibraryProject named FirstProject.Entities

I have created a class named "Customer"

```
namespace FirstProject.Entities
{   
public class Customer
{
    public virtual int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual string State { get; set; }
    public virtual int Zip { get; set; }
}
}
```

Then I created a Mapping class

```
namespace FirstProject.Entities
{
public class CusotmerMap : ClassMap<Customer> 
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.CustomerID).Column("CustomerID").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Map(x => x.CustomerName);
        Map(x => x.Address1);
        Map(x => x.Address2);
        Map(x => x.City);
        Map(x => x.Zip);           
    }
}
}
```

I now don't know how to proceed further. Am I doing it right.. please suggest

how to configure and proceed further

Answer (score 2):

The following is Fluent

```
Id(x => x.CustomerID).Column("CustomerID").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
```

I use Fluent assertions, like the following

```
actual.Should().BeGreaterThan(1).And().LessThan(2);
```

Fluent is basically where you chain together the commands such that it reads quite well.

Auto mapping is where you do nothing. Everything is done by conventions. I tend to use Auto. Fluent is nice if you don't follow conventions.

Based on your mapping, the CustomerId being Assigned is not the out-of-the-box convention. As such you need to either

1. Use **Fluent** to specify exactly how it should map. This is just like doing it the standard way in XML, but with a *fluent* interface.
2. Use Auto and specify a **Convention** that will automatically change CustomerId to be Assigned.
3. Use Auto and specify an **Override**, that will use Auto but override CustomerId to be Assigned.

If you want to do option 3, here is the code:

```
var model = AutoMap
    .AssemblyOf<Customer>()
    .Where(IsMapped)
    .Override<Customer>(a => a.Id(b => b.CustomerId, "CustomerId").GeneratedBy.Assigned());
```

The function IsMapped must return True for entities you want to Map.

Comment: Thanks Lain for the explanation.. When you say AutoMap, is the database table created for you by Nhibernate? Since, I already have an existing database I just need to create the DataAccess Layer for it through NHibernate, because all the tables are already created with Identity keys. Do you think Option 1 suits for this scenario?

Comment: Also are there any books on Fluent NHibernate. I could not find any

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I learnt it by reading the doco on the website, and questions here on SO.